# Cordova app quits after being at background for a while

Tags: javascript, android, background, cordova

My Phonegap/cordova app goes to background (pause state) on pressing the home button. Within a few minutes, when tapping my app icon, it will resume quickly (i.e., on the same screen when it went to background). But if a longer period elapsed (e.g., tens of minutes?), when I tap the icon, the app will start as the first time (e.g., start from the splash page and go the index.html after loading).

How can I prevent the app from existing when putting to background for long? I don't want the user to wait for long in such a case (I overwrite the back button listener so user can actually quit the app in that way).

I'm not sure if any "background service" plugin is required or not, as I don't have background services, just want it acts as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your activity enters the [paused state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html), the system calls the onPause() method on your Activity, which allows you to stop ongoing actions that should not continue while paused or persist any information that should be permanently saved in case the user continues to leave your app. If the user returns to your activity from the paused state, the system resumes it and calls the onResume() method. So you can do the followings.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    // save the current configuration or state  here on sharedPref
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // retrieve the instance configuration or state here from shared pref.
}
```

Comment: So why after a short period of stepping into pause state, the app can correctly resume itself, but auto quit after longer pause?

Comment: If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely restarted and restored to its previous state. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle